# Global переменные. Можно ли сократить в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

Хотел задать вопрос.

1. Можно ли как-то сократить код в Python за счет каких либо манипуляций над Global переменными?
2. Как правильно называть "global" в Python (переменная/функция/тип данных)?
3. Почему при работе с списком (list) не нужно писать "global"

Вот сам код:

```
kolvo = 0
cena = 0
name = []
i = 0


def add_item(item_name, item_cost):
    slov = item_name + ' - ' + str(item_cost)
    name.append(slov)
    global cena #именно про эти две строки и их сокращение
    global kolvo #именно про эти три строки и их сокращение
    cena += item_cost
    kolvo += 1
    

def print_receipt():
    global i
    global cena #именно про эти три строки и их сокращение
    global kolvo #именно про эти три строки и их сокращение
    global name #именно про эти три строки и их сокращение
    if cena != 0:
        i += 1
        print('Чек', str(i) + '.', 'Всего предметов:', str(kolvo))
        for gg in range(len(name)):
            print(name[gg], sep='/n')
        print('Итого:', cena)
        print('-----')
        kolvo = 0
        cena = 0 
        name = []
```

*Заранее огромное спасибо!*

Comment: `global i, cena, kolvo, name`

Comment: 3. Потому что вы редактируете существующий объект, а не помещаете в переменную какой-то новый объект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Подстановка переменных **через запятую**. В этом примере: `global i, cena, kolvo, name`
2. *Скорее всего*, можно назвать **функцией** для определения области видимости переменной.
3. Потому что вы редактируете **существующий** объект, а не помещаете в переменную какой-то новый объект.

Comment: У функции должны быть скобки. Скорее это оператор что ли, не помню как правильно называется.

Answer (score 1):

Вам вообще не нужны глобальные переменные.

```
class MyClass():
    kolvo = 0
    cena = 0
    name = []
    i = 0

    def add_item(self, item_name, item_cost):
        slov = item_name + ' - ' + str(item_cost)
        self.name.append(slov)
#        global cena #именно про эти две строки и их сокращение
#        global kolvo #именно про эти три строки и их сокращение
        self.cena += item_cost
        self.kolvo += 1
        

    def print_receipt(self):
#        global i
#        global cena #именно про эти три строки и их сокращение
#        global kolvo #именно про эти три строки и их сокращение
#        global name #именно про эти три строки и их сокращение
        if self.cena != 0:
            self.i += 1
            print(f'Чек {self.i}. Всего предметов: {self.kolvo}')
            for gg in range(len(self.name)):
                print(self.name[gg], sep='/n')
            print(f'Итого: {self.cena:>4}')
            print('-' * 12)
            self.kolvo = 0
            self.cena = 0 
            self.name = []
        
myClass = MyClass()
myClass.add_item('Name_1', 12)
myClass.add_item('Name_2', 42)
myClass.print_receipt()
```

Comment: Спасибо, но вопрос был задан про другое.